# If statement for url segement to display certain as well as overlapping images

Tags: channel-images, mx-google-map

I have a map and on this map are about 3 images. However the map displays different images on it every month. See code:

```
 <div class="col-sm-11 map">
                            {exp:channel:entries 
                                       channel="mapped" 
                                       status="open|Draft" 
                                       entry_id="1354"
                                       orderby="mapped_date" 
                                       sort="asc"}
                                <div id="container">
                                    {exp:channel_images:images field_id="336" entry_id="{entry_id}" category="included" limit="4"}
                                    <img data-x="{image:field:1}" data-y="{image:field:2}" src="{image:url}" />
                                    {/exp:channel_images:images}
                                </div>
                                    {/exp:channel:entries}

                                <div class="map-canvas">
                                    <img src="/images/picture1"/>
                                </div>
                            <div class="xsmall-pad"></div>
                            </div>
```

How do I specify that I want the images to only appear for a certain month - the title for that month is specified in the 3rd segment of the url. And how do I get the 3 images to overlap on top of the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was more complicated than I first laid it out to be. We had to create a plugin for it. No answer here because the solution specifically fixed a feature that is not found normally. But yes, Nick Benson's points on URL segments is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values of URL segments with `{segment_1}`, `{segment_2}`, and so on.

```
{if "{segment_3}" == "january"}
     <h1>It's January!</h1>
{/if}
```

The `segment_N` syntax is available natively in EE; when you're ready to do more advanced things with URL segments, take a look at [URL Helper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper).